# I'm having an issue with jQuery variables

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a series of list items which contain data attributes to store information such as this:

```
<li data-name="John Doe" data-age="42" data-gender="male">...</li>
```

I am using that information to populate a popover injected using jQuery and I need to store the information to variables corresponding to each list item. I am using `.click()` to append the popover to the list item and then fade it in. But when I attempted to include the variables in the function to limit their scope, my code stopped working correctly. Here is a rough example of what I had:

```
var person = $('#list li');

person.click( function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name'),
        age = $(this).attr('data-age'),
        gender = $(this).attr('data-gender');

    $(this).children('div.foo').fadeIn();
})
    .append(
        '<div class="foo">
             <dl>
                 <dt>Name:</dt>
                 <dd>' + name + '</dd>
                 <dt>Age:</dt>
                 <dd>' + age + '</dd>
                 <dt>Gender:</dt>
                 <dd>' + gender + '</dd>
             </dl>
         </div>'
    );
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working as I would like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `name, age and gender` are only visible to the scope of the `click` function, so you can't use them in the append block below that.

```
var person = $('#list li');

person.click( function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name'),
        age = $(this).attr('data-age'),
        gender = $(this).attr('data-gender');
    $(this).append( '<div class="foo">
             <dl>
                 <dt>Name:</dt>
                 <dd>' + name + '</dd>
                 <dt>Age:</dt>
                 <dd>' + age + '</dd>
                 <dt>Gender:</dt>
                 <dd>' + gender + '</dd>
             </dl>
         </div>');
     $(this).children('div.foo').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Using your code I am able to get it to work, BUT only if I click the list item twice, as my first click does nothing.

Comment: I edited the answer and placed `fadeIn()` after `append`, does that help?

Comment: That fixes it, but now it is throwing out other functionality that I had in the popover, such as a close button.

Comment: it's hard to know how this code affects the rest of your functionality. Could you post more code, or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post what I am working on; confidentiality and all that (hence the generic code that I have used). Basically, the issue is that sticking the append method inside the click function means that it isn't seen when the page loads, and so a whole bunch of other stuff I have that uses the appended markup doesn't work.

Comment: I see, okay, I extracted the code that does the appending into its own function, now it's called when the page loads or when a user clicks on an `li`

Comment: Nice try; still no cigar. This is probably a separate question though. If you revert your edits I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: No need to be sorry, I appreciate your help! I have found a solution (I'm assuming it isn't bad practice as jQuery is built using functions within functions, but I'm a JS noob); I am nesting the click functions that relate to the popover within the click function for the list items.

Answer (score 0):

Your having a scope issue.  The variables are not created until the `li` is clicked but your `append` is outside of the click.

Also, use `.data` instead of `attr`.

Comment: Why should I be using the data method instead of attr?

Comment: `data` will handle these attributes as well as anything set with `data` if you end up using that in the future.  Also just seems a bit more readable in the code.

Comment: So would my usage be the same, simply replacing 'attr' with 'data'?